# How to use "this" variables in stateless component to handle mouse events

Tags: javascript, reactjs, functional-programming, react-hooks

let's say I have this class component where I have to check if mouse is holding click, track coordinates and do some stuff. I used to create class in which I could store "this" variables to access them through the component.
How can I handle those kind of variables in a functional component without the need to create a class? I'm aware the old method will re-render the state only when the state changes (ideal situation), with the new method it will be kind of a problem, right? 
In my case I need to use this.increment variable (and few more) through other functions that are in my component.

```
class MyComp extends React.Component{
    onMouseDown(e){
        this.isMouseDown = true;
        this.startX = e.clientX
        this.startY = e.clientY
    }
    onMouseMove(e){
        let x = e.clientX;
        let y = e.clientY;
        if (this.isMouseDown){
            this.increment = this.startY - y
            // do stuff with this.startX and this.startY
            // ....
        }
    }
    onMouseUp(){
        this.isMouseDown = false;
    }
    render() {
        return <div onMouseDown={this.onMouseDown.bind(this)}
                    onMouseMove={this.onMouseMove.bind(this)}
                    onMouseUp={this.onMouseUp.bind(this)} />
    }
}
```

How can I achieve the same thing with a functional component like this ?

```
function MyComp ({ text }) {
    return  <div onMouseDown={e => onMouseDown(e)}
                onMouseMove={e => onMouseMove(e)}
                onMouseUp={e => onMouseUp(e)}>
                {text}
            </div>
}
```

Thanks for you time!

Answer (score 0):

Read more about useRef and useCallback hooks. Using those, You can create state-independent references to variables and callbacks inside the functional component.

[Hooks reference in React.js docs](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html)

Here is Your class-component logic refactored to use hooks:

```
function MyComp ({ text }) {
    const trackData = React.useRef({});

    const onMouseDown = React.useCallback((e) => {
        trackData.current.isMouseDown = true;
        trackData.current.startX = e.clientX
        trackData.current.startY = e.clientY
    }, [trackData]);

    ...

    return  <div onMouseDown={e => onMouseDown(e)}
                onMouseMove={e => onMouseMove(e)}
                onMouseUp={e => onMouseUp(e)}>
                {text}
            </div>
}
```

Answer (score 0):

JS allows creating functions inside functions. You may create a functional React component that has few function definitions that can be used as your requirement as follows:

```
function MyComp ({ text }) {
    const onMouseDown = (evt) => {
        ... //your code goes here
    }
    ... // same for onMouseMove & onMouseUp
    return  <div onMouseDown={e => onMouseDown(e)}
                onMouseMove={e => onMouseMove(e)}
                onMouseUp={e => onMouseUp(e)}>
                {text}
            </div>
}
```